# How do I make the weight column in my medical log sheet get updated with the most recent weigh-in?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, formatting

I am looking to get the weight column in my medical log sheet to be updated automatically when I key in the new weights on my Weight Log sheet. I take the weights weekly and update the info into a new column. How could I do this? Please note I want to keep the log so I dont want to have to delete past weigh ins.

[image: Weight Log]

[image: Medical Log]

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Please [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/168884/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with another table that shows your manually entered desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `reduce()` and `filter()`, like this:

```
=reduce( 
  "", filter('Weight Log'!B$2:Z, 'Weight Log'!A$2:A = A2), 
  lambda( 
    result, current, 
    if( len(current), current, result ) 
  ) 
)
```